# Is automatic disabling of DML triggers possible during SSDT publish?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, ssdt, deployment

During ssdt deployment I am concerned about having DML triggers in place on tables that may slow down performance of table recreation a lot.

We are facing the issue that the column order in the table scripts is different than in the target servers. Because [Microsoft does not provide an option to ignore this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/1221587), the tables are recreated during publishing to ensure the same column order.

This process is very very slow. And since some tables do have DML triggers enabled, I am concerned this makes it even more slow than required. I looked for options to disable / ignore those triggers during deployment but could not find any. How are we expected to realize that?

Comment: Why are you suspecting that DML triggers are slowing you down?

Comment: Because the whole table is getting re-created and I guess records are put into a temp table and re-inserted to the new table. This should fiire any insert triggers, shoudn't it?

Comment: Any further ideas?

Comment: You might consider using a pre and post deploy scripting to manually search for and disable any triggers. My answer below gets you halfway there. You'll want to populate a temporary table with a list of the disabled triggers from the predeploy script then re-enable them in a postdeploy script (making sure to not leave leftover records that would mess up subsequent publishes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my first-hand experience, SSDT refreshes table definitions before it refreshes triggers.

I had to manually disable all triggers before publishing for it to work (sample reasoning below). However, it is foolish to assume all table triggers were enabled before, so [turning them all off then back on](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/09/05/sql-server-how-to-enable-or-disable-all-the-triggers-on-a-table-and-database/) is prone to causing issues.

My solution was to create a script to generate the necessary SQL to turn off all currently-enabled triggers, and then to enable them again (make sure to set current database connection to your target database).

**Warning:** Single user mode will close all open connections. **Make sure to re-enable multi-user mode after you're done.** You can skip changing user mode altogether if nobody is holding any locks on your system.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(255) = 'YOURDATABASE'
PRINT 'ALTER DATABASE ' + @DatabaseName + ' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;'
DECLARE @TableTriggersOnly BIT = 1
CREATE TABLE #Trigger
(
     SchemaName NVARCHAR(255)
    ,TableName NVARCHAR(255)
    ,TriggerName NVARCHAR(255)
    ,WasDisabled BIT
)
INSERT INTO #Trigger
(
     SchemaName
    ,TableName
    ,TriggerName
    ,WasDisabled
)
SELECT
     SchemaName = S.name
    ,TableName = T.name
    ,TriggerName = Tr.name
    ,WasDisabled = Tr.is_disabled
FROM
    sys.triggers AS Tr
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS T ON
        T.object_id = Tr.parent_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON
        S.schema_id = T.schema_id
WHERE
    Tr.is_disabled = 0
    AND (@TableTriggersOnly = 0 OR Tr.parent_class = 1)
DECLARE
     @SchemaName NVARCHAR(255)
    ,@TableName NVARCHAR(255)
    ,@TriggerName NVARCHAR(255)
    ,@WasDisabled BIT
DECLARE TriggerCursor CURSOR STATIC FOR
    SELECT
         SchemaName
        ,TableName
        ,TriggerName
        ,WasDisabled
    FROM #Trigger
OPEN TriggerCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TriggerCursor INTO
     @SchemaName
    ,@TableName
    ,@TriggerName
    ,@WasDisabled
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT 'DISABLE TRIGGER ' + @SchemaName+'.'+@TriggerName + ' ON ' + @SchemaName+'.'+@TableName + ';'
    FETCH NEXT FROM TriggerCursor INTO
         @SchemaName
        ,@TableName
        ,@TriggerName
        ,@WasDisabled
END
CLOSE TriggerCursor
/*
 * YOUR STATEMENTS HERE
 */
PRINT '/*******************'
PRINT 'YOUR STATEMENTS HERE'
PRINT '*******************/'
/*
 * YOUR STATEMENTS HERE
 */
OPEN TriggerCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TriggerCursor INTO
     @SchemaName
    ,@TableName
    ,@TriggerName
    ,@WasDisabled
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT 'ENABLE TRIGGER ' + @SchemaName+'.'+@TriggerName + ' ON ' + @SchemaName+'.'+@TableName + ';'
    FETCH NEXT FROM TriggerCursor INTO
         @SchemaName
        ,@TableName
        ,@TriggerName
        ,@WasDisabled
END
CLOSE TriggerCursor
DEALLOCATE TriggerCursor
PRINT 'ALTER DATABASE ' + @DatabaseName + ' SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;'
DROP TABLE #Trigger
```

A particular table of mine has a trigger that was poorly written, encountering errors when handling multiple affected rows at a time, but the correction to the trigger to handle the case was never getting applied. So a column alteration in the table meant that SSDT was shifting data to a temp table then back, causing a multi-row invocation of the table trigger.