# SSDT Publish failing with an error without even running any statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssdt

My publish attempts are failing with this error

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 7572 All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Taking the [old-school advice to print](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214333/140226) status messages between deployment script execution, I have narrowed it down to this:

[image]

<sub>The line number mismatches because of SQL Server quirks, which is why you have to `PRINT` stuff like a heathen (see the link above)</sub>

Note how there were literally no statements executed. I also had a verbose trace running which confirms that nothing was executed:

[image]

How could the control flow statements between two `PRINT` statements possibly cause an error?!

Comment: I was going to say, line 7572 in the error message does not match line 31890 that you've highlighted in the screen shot.

Comment: Which is yet another reason why debugging SQL Server issues is infuriating. I have updated my post to mention this **giant** violation of the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: I think newer versions of SSMS address this issue but I don’t know if/when they will get adopted in SSDT.

Comment: Can confirm, double-clicking the error message finally takes me to the correct line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `GO` statement segregated the successful code from the remainder, which indeed contains an erroneous statement (as per the error message), and so the error was thrown during **syntax validation**.

By taking the line number of the `GO` statement and adding the line number shown in the error message (which is really the offset in the batch), I found a bad `MERGE` statement, since double-clicking the error message in the SSDT publish results takes me to a random spot in the publish script.

So it was caused by statement batching, with syntax validation finally running on a deployment script (that is excluded from building with the SQL project).